# Web API routing 404 not found

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm getting a 404 not found error when trying to access one of my Web API actions:

I have in my WebAPIConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
      name: "DefaultApi",
      routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
      defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I have a controller named OnSourceAPIController and a GET action ValidateServiceRequestAuto.

I get a 404 error when I try to go to:

```
http://localhost/api/OnSourceAPI/ValidateServiceRequestAuto
```

My first guess was I had some kind of routing error, but I created an mvc controller and an index page for it and was able to browse there normally via this routing (api/controller/action). The builtin api/help page even shows /api/OnSourceAPI/ValidateServiceRequestAuto as the route to my api call.

I also tried using the WebAPIRouteDebugger tool. It gives me a 000 404 not found error when I use

```
http://localhost/api/OnSourceAPI/ValidateServiceRequestAuto
```

, but actually give me the normal route information if I take localhost off of the front and just use

```
api/OnSourceAPI/ValidateServiceRequestAuto as the URL...
```

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out and feel a little bit silly now.

I have my webapi project running inside of my normal website project with a path of .../api, so because I set up my api routing to be api/controller/action, the path I really need to use is localhost/**api/api**/controller/action. So it turns out that the 404 was there because it really couldn't find anything at that location. I hate it when computers do exactly what you tell them to.

Comment: I didn't have the exact same problem, but this helped me figure it out. I was calling the service from the WebClient class and my BaseAddress was missing a '/' at the end. So I think it was probably calling localhost/apiapi/controller/action.

Comment: I just had the exact same problem and also feel a little bit silly! Thank you for sharing your issue, I don't know how much longer I would have been chasing this otherwise

Comment: Are you sure that you need the 'action' part of the URL? Web API implies that you are mapping HTTP verbs to actions of the same name in the controller (of ApiController).

Comment: Just make sure you have good global.asax in your project has below code, web api (without MVC areas)  public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was address of created service: `WebApp.Start(address)`

Should be like: http://localhost:9000/

NOT: http://localhost:9000/api/